# The recipient does not receive any push message even though

Tags: ruby, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm able to send push notifications to $RECIPIENT when I'm using console.firebase.com.
If I send with [spacialdb/fcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm), then no push is sent. Even though the reply from the server looks ok. => *(:status_code=>200, :response=>"success")*

Any idea what might be wrong?

**code**

```
require 'fcm'

fcm = FCM.new('$TOKEN')
registration_ids = ['$RECIPIENT']

options = { data: { score: '123' }, collapse_key: 'updated_score' }
response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
puts "Sendt: #{response}"
```

**running code**

```
$ ruby fcm.rb

Sendt: {:body=>"{\"multicast_id\":60356242858746826,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,
\"canonical_ids\":0,
    \"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1528896392320437%e06a962bca0e\"}]}", 
:headers=>{"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"],
    "date"=>["Wed, 13 Jun 2018 13:26:32 GMT"], "expires"=>["Wed, 13 Jun 2018 13:26:32 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"],
    "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], 
"x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"],
    "server"=>["GSE"], "alt-svc"=>["quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"43,42,41,39,35\""],
    "accept-ranges"=>["none"], "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"],
     "connection"=>["close"]}, :status_code=>200, :response=>"success",
    :canonical_ids=>[], :not_registered_ids=>[]}
```

Comment: What platform is your recipient?

Answer (score 0):

The example push code on github.com/spacialdb/fcm was just sending a *data* push. Since I had not configured my iPhone app to listen to that I could not see that I received any.

To send a push notification you need to follow this syntax:

```
  # See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http for more details.

    fcm = FCM.new("API_KEY")
    fcm.send(
       registration_ids: ["4sdsx", "8sdsd"], 
       { "notification": 
          { "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark", 
             "text": "5 to 1" 
          }, 
       }
   )
```

I've created a [PR to update the docs](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm/compare/master...stabenfeldt:patch-1) at fcm. Hopefully, they'll accept and make it easier for the next guy. :-)